# Using Java Script or jQuery to count for specific items and create hash map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data like this:

```
A,10,USA
B,20,UK
A,5,USA
```

and the output has to be like this:

```
A has ran 15 miles with average of 7.5
B has ran 20 miles with average of 20
```

in jQuery I have written a code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
               $('#calculate').click(function(){
                $('#report').empty();
                var data = $('#input').val();



                 $.each($.csv.toArrays(data), function(_, row) {

                     var namecount = 0
                     $(row[0]).each(function(){
                        namecount++; 
                     });

                     var totalevents = 0;
                     $(row[1]).each(function(){
                        totalmiles++; 
                     });

                     var average = totalmiles / namecount;

                     $('#report').append('<div>' + row[0] + ' has ran ' + totalmiles +"  "+'miles with an average of'+"  "+average +'</div>');
                 });
               });
            });
```

but the code counts 0 and NaN for total miles and average. I have tried to use Hashtable in jQuery to take care of this, but I have not found a good guide on showing me how I can make it happen by javascript or jQuery to make these calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems but the biggest is you need one loop to collect the information and a second loop to display it. I doubt this is quite right without trying it.

```
var totals = {};

$.each($.csv.toArrays(data), function(_, row) {

   var prev = totals[row[0]];
   if (!prev) {
      prev = {};
      prev.miles = 0;
      prev.count = 0;
      totals[row[0]] = prev;
   }

   prev.miles += row[1];
   prev.count++;
});

for (key in totals) {
   value = totals[key];
   $('#report').append('<div>' + key + ' has run ' + value.miles +"  miles with an average of  "+(value.miles / value.count)+'</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this is as your main code:

```
var aggregates = {};

$.each($.csv.toArrays(data), function(_, row) {
    var id = row[0];
    var miles = row[1];
    if (aggregates[id] === undefined) {
        aggregates[id] = {
            count : 0,
            miles : 0
        };
    }
    aggregates[id].miles += parseInt(miles);
    aggregates[id].count++;
});

for (id in aggregates) {
    $("#report").append(id + " ran " + aggregates[id].miles + " miles with average of " + (aggregates[id].miles / aggregates[id].count));
}
```

Here's the fiddle for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Ev7V/

Here the aggregates object works as a hashtable with the id as key, and the object holding count and miles as value.